# MDAPI to DX Question

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

What I want to do is convert all the files in a particular folder in my project that are currently in mdapi format, convert them to source format, add the converted results to a corresponding folder under my dx **force-app** folder, and push the results back to my source control.

In the project outline detailed below, in the root **layouts** folder I have layout1.layout, layout2.layout, et al such that they are converted to DX source format, which so far I've tried:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r ./layouts -d output/
```

returns:

> the path specified is not a directory or doesn't contain a package.xml

If I try running `sfdx force:source:convert -r ./layouts -d output/` instead I get:

**Expected file at path: C:\Users\me\projectname\layouts\layout1.layout-meta.xml**

In my use case I have the following in a source control'd repo:

```
.sfdx
.vscode
config
force-app/main/default.... all regular default project folders
layouts/
     layout1.layout
     layout2.layout
     layout3.layout
     ...
manifest/package.xml
sfdx-project.json
```

My reasoning for this is to be able to deployed what I eventually have in source control at a later time.

Comment: If this is an SFDX project that you created, it should already be in Source format.  You'd have to go out of your way to convert it back into Metadata format, which is what some of those other `sfdx` commands do.  What are you trying to accomplish at the end of the day?

Comment: @BrianMiller in this case we have the DX project as desired. However, on the same branch in source control, there is this hanging `layouts` folder that is in MDAPI format. I just want to convert it to source format, and the changes into my repo, and push it all back to source control for deployment later

Comment: Consider just retrieving the `layouts` from the original org and it'll bring them into your project in Source form, then can push them to the report?  If you already have a `package.xml` file with the layouts, then you can use `sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml -u MyOrg` to get those layouts from the most up to date org.  See [Develop Against Any Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm) for a nice list of commands and options for `force:source:retrieve`

Comment: Cheers @BrianMiller will give this a go!

Comment: Let us know how it goes.  Also, consider updating your question and stating at the beginning the original problem (about the same branch, different formats, etc) so that future viewers will have a full context right away